# high latency pings to router

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, latency

I am using a wireless network, wondering why when pinging the router I sometimes get high pings. shouldn't the time be <1ms all the time?

[image: at]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows' Wireless Zero Configuration, it will attempt to scan for new SSIDs every so often. This often causes some latency spikes. Try doing one of the following and see if it helps:

- Upgrade your wireless card's drivers, especially if you're using the native Windows ones. A manufacturer's wireless utility will often replace the functionality of Wireless Zero Config
- Disable Wireless Zero Config once you're connected to the network.

Comment: My wireless card drivers are already up to date. Disabling wireless zero config doesnt seem to do anything for me.